# Can I do code injection into apps without jailbreaking my device?

Tags: ios, objective-c-runtime

Been reading about the [FLEX Library](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLEX) for iOS, and I use it in my existing app. In the section "learning from other apps" it says the code injection exercise is left to the reader. Is it possible to go about doing this without jailbreaking the device?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It won't be possible to use FLEX with an app that you are not compiling yourself. There is [FLEXLoader](https://github.com/qiaoxueshi/FLEXLoader), but that will require your device to be jailbroken.

Comment: This is not true. It is just very complex for one to do, but entirely possible and I have done it before.

Comment: Injecting your own code in to a running iOS process would be a fairly large security concern. If it is indeed possible at least link to an example, or somewhere to start.

Comment: take a look at theos jailed on github. FlexLoader also works as a dylib injected into apps non jailbroken.

Comment: Ah I was not aware of this project. Note that this answer is over 2 years old ;) Feel free to create a proper answer and I will link it in mine since it is no longer accurate.

Comment: gotcha, will up you and hopefully OP sees.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other ways discussed in @joseph Duffy's answer/comments, you can also use a secondary device which **is** jailbroken to decrypt an app, package it back into an IPA, and then patch it by linking a libary to the IPA with your own code, finally re-signing it for your other device. Its a bit of a pain as a regular workflow, but works.

Check this out: https://medium.com/@kennethpoon/how-to-perform-ios-code-injection-on-ipa-files-1ba91d9438db